# problems in displaying a text in the center

Tags: dompdf

i am using dompdf to generate pdf files in joomla. I have problems in displaying a text in the center. i tried both css and inline methods in table td. Nothing worked.

Thanks

Comment: It isn't multiline text, is it? _(Know nothing about dompdf)_

Comment: not its not multiline padding works fine but not align="center" or text-align="center"

Comment: In the center of what? The page? The table cell? How does the PDF created by dompdf compare to viewing the HTML in a web browser? Post some sample HTML so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: I resolved this issue by copying latest dompdf library into the joomla library folder. Now center alignment of text in pDF works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by copying latest dompdf library into the joomla library folder. Now center alignment of text in pDF works perfectly.